# What is the name of this spikes insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Location is South India.

Behavior: It is not moving.

Month: May,

Place: No people come. (Actually species chooses the place on my next door, where neighbors left 2 months ago)

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more details? Location, type of habitat, size, how long it has been there, do you see them often etc.

Comment: @arboviral I added new HD image, is that quite enough to ID the species?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Creature is "**Debris-carrying Lacewing.**".

[image]

([Source](http://2020iscoming.info/else/brown-lacewing-larvae.coming))

Comment: Attention: I get a high-risk warning when clicking the link!

Comment: @AlexDeLarge Same for me

Comment: Well then, I'm not going to click on it...